# R export to files readable to SAS

Tags: r, import, export, sas

My workflow is as below.

1. SAS exports a dataset to `file1`
2. R imports `file1`, then exports to `file2`
3. SAS imports `file2` and continue.

Ideally,

Step 1 uses `proc export` in SAS to get `file1.xlsx`

Step 2 uses `read.xlsx` in R to import `file1.xlsx` and then outputs to `file2.xlsx` via `write.xlsx`

Step 3 uses `proc import` to import `file2.xlsx` into SAS.

The problem is, I can't install package `xlsx` in R.

**What I have done:**

1. Step 1: `file1.csv`
2. Step 2: `read.table` import `file1.csv` then `write.table` to export to `file2.csv`

But the content in `file2.csv` is compressed into one column. If I use `write.table` to export to `file2.xlsx`, then the file is `damaged, can't be opened`.

**Here's the question**

Is there any substitue for package `xlsx` in R that can implement xlsx file import and export?

OR

Is there any file format that is readable to both SAS and R? What's the relevant procedure/function to do import/export?

Comment: You can try `XLConnect` or `readxl` library  https://github.com/hadley/readxl

Comment: What do you mean by "the content in file2.csv is totally in a mass"?

Comment: @nicola It seems all the data was stored in one column. It's like a n by k data set is compressed as n by 1. Every first cell in a row contains all the data in its row.

Comment: Read the help `?write.table`. You can set the format of your output file. I bet that you messed something up while reading the first file or by not setting the proper options while writing the output file.

Comment: @nicola Reading the first file seems OK. `write.table` can't write data to `.xlsx`?

Comment: No, it can't. But you can for sure write in a format that can be read by SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `write.table` with `write.csv` then everything is OK.

Comment: Still want to have `.xlsx` file output for other purpose. I will check it out. @akrun.

Comment: I think the delimiter was the problem  I don't know why `write.table` didn't work for you

Comment: You mean `write.table` can export data to `.xlsx`?

Comment: I don't usually deal with `.xls` dataset, so I am not sure